# 'WHERE' clause does not work with both conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `calls` (
   `fullname` varchar(201) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `lastname` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
   `firstname` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
   `call` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `phoneNumber` char(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

`call` stores information regarding the date and time of the call made by the user

I am trying to select all the persons that called at least three times between 8 P.M. and 10 P.M. in the last month.

My query:

```
SELECT fullname, call, COUNT(fullname) AS NumberOfCalls
FROM calls
WHERE HOUR(call) IN (20,21) AND datediff(CURDATE(), call) < 30
GROUP BY fullname
HAVING NumberOfCalls >= 3;
```

The query does not provide a result.

If i comment `/* AND datediff(CURDATE(), call) < 30 */` i get all persons that called between 8 pm and 10 pm.

If i comment `/* HOUR(call) IN (20,21) AND */` i get all persons that called in the last month.

The WHERE clause does not work with both conditions, and I do not understand why. How can i make it accept both conditions? Thank you!

Comment: Your query is wrong. `call` isn't in the `GROUP BY` clause but in the list of columns without being applied to an aggregation function. Older versions or a poor configuration may accept this, but the results may be funny. Apart from that please [edit] your question and add sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements, **no** images) and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: @stickybit The values of `call` will be unpredictable, but it should still return the correct `fullname` values, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are you sure that there were calls between 8 and 10 in the last month? I can't think of any other reason why the combined `WHERE` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, `fullname` should be OK. But what's the point of `call` in it anyway, if it's unpredictable and apparently not even wanted? Just breaks the query if they port it to another version or configuration. Or it may be misleading at least.

Comment: You have the arguments to `datediff()` in the wrong order. The later date should be the first argument.

Comment: Because of that, the `datediff` check shouldn't have any affect (I assume all calls are in the past). Which makes it even more curious that commenting it out makes any difference. There must be something else going on.[

Comment: I believe the problem was with the datediff function, as you indicated. After loading new data into the table and using a direct comparison on the date value, the query returns the correct answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think your code should work.  The `call` in the `SELECT` is inappropriate (because it is not part of the `GROUP BY`).  And I recommend direct comparisons on the date/time values:

```
SELECT fullname, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfCalls
FROM calls c
WHERE HOUR(call) IN (20, 21) AND call >= curdate() - interval 30 day
GROUP BY fullname
HAVING NumberOfCalls >= 3;
```

Comment: The direct comparison is especially useful if there's an index on the `call` column.

Comment: Thank you! I believe the problem was with the datediff function. After using a direct comparison on the date value the query returns the correct answer.